# Execute batch working when executed anonymously but not when called from my vfp controller

Tags: visualforce, batch

I have a controller that extends a vfp that calls execute on a batch

```
 BatchableScorer bs = new BatchableScorer(passedContacts);
 ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(bs);
```

though when it fires up i can see that job hasn't started in the apex jobs list but when i check the status in the debug console it states that it's "holding". If I then look in the Apex Jobs list, that job is not listed.
When i go to execute anonymous window and run the code there, though, it runs as expected (and shows in the Job list). Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of VFP does the class extend? Does it require Admin permissions to use like the Console does? One route is more "direct" than the other. Have you looked in the Flex queue instead of the Apex Batch jobs list?

Comment: the vfp is contact standard controller, <apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="passedContacts" extensions="BatchProscore">
have checked out the flex queue and nothing there either

Comment: and i am running and executing all code as the admin user

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to start batch classes from visualforce pages, but I'm fairly confident, the controller extension will need to implement the Database.Batchable Interface for you to do that. See [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#apex_batch_scheduleBatch_section) for more on this.

Comment: Are you sure? if the controller extension implements `Database.Batchable`, then it has to have `start()`, `execute()`, and `finish()` methods. Class `BatchableScorer` is the one that should implement `Database.Batchable`

Comment: @cropredy. As I stated, I've never done it before. I know his batch class need to impliment `Database.Batchable`. It seems that his VisualForce controller needs to be doing something else to get the `Database.BatchableContext`. He might want to consider using the `Database.schedulable` interface to schedule a 1 time batch job. At a minimum, his extension needs to be `public` and possibly `global`. Those are the things that come to mind for me.

Answer (score 0):

got it. in order to use the standard controller to get the selectedContacts and be able to kickoff the batch match was in my vfp page.
I use contact as the standardController, recordsetVar of passedContacts,
extending BatchProScoreController and applying the action of generateBatch

Action:

```
    public void generateBatch(){
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
```

and by calling (this) I was able to keep the checked contacts instead of calling a new instance of the BatchProScoreController.
Headache

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling batch instance from a method that is called from the constructor of the Visual Force page controller or you must be calling batch instance from the constructor itself. try and call that batch instance from a method that is called on the action of Visual Force page.

Note : you cannot call batch from constructor

Comment: Please do not ask for votes or best answer on SFSE.

Comment: @DavidReed I just asked so that, others get help from it and they can refer to the correct answer.